# In Windows 7 how to create desktop shortcut to a webpage and then edit it to provide more query-string args

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

I can drag the icon from the IE address bar onto the desktop, and a shortcut to the webpage is created on the desktop. The type is "Pinned Site Shortcut". I'd like to edit the URL, to provide additional query-string arguments.  But when I right-click on the shortcut, there's no way to do that. Can it be done?

Comment: It can. The shortcut is just a Platin Text file that can be edited With every Text editor

Answer (score 3):

As @nixda points out in his comment, the shortcuts are just plain text files, you can edit them in any text editor you'd like.

Here's an easy way:

- Open Notepad.
- Drag the pinned site icon on to Notepad's open window.
- Edit the URL.
- Save the changes.